# Ros PX4 Gazebo - some ready-made models do not start and give an error

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, px4

I created the new model according to the instructions. Error on startup. I also get the same error if I run some of the list of available models. For example:models iris, plane, plane_catapult, boat - start normally; models iris_rplidar, iris_opt_flow, plane_lidar, iris_foggy_lidar - do not start and give an error.
For example, I change the model name in the file mavros_posix_sitl.launch

```
<arg name="vehicle" default="...."/>
```

I don't understand what the problem could be.

[image]

Comment: Please paste the error as text. Screenshots are not text-searchable. Thanks.